# How to animate png with Matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to animate an png by moving it with changing its x position but the the loop doesn't overwrite the previous step but instead it just leave it and show a new version beside it:

[first step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuTST.png)

[Final step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRMtb.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.image as mgimg

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.axis([0, 400, 0, 300])


def animate(i):
    imobj = ax.imshow(np.zeros((0,0)),extent=[0+i, 67+i, 136, 100], aspect='auto',zorder=1)
    fname='catapult0.png'
    img = mgimg.imread(fname)[-1::-1]
    imobj.set_data(img)
    return imobj,
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,
                               frames=100,
                               interval=5,
                               repeat=False)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You need to define `imobj = ax.imshow()` *outside* of the animating function. Else you create a new image every time this function is called.

Comment: If i defined the object outside of the function, how would i access and change its position from inside the animating function?

Comment: Did you even try it?

Comment: Yes i'v tried multiple solutions and the last one was to create multiple versions of the PNG itself each with a different x displacement but I am looking for a solution from the code itself by accessing the object position..

Comment: Did you try to put `imobj = ax.imshow()` outside of the animating function? If not, please do so, post the code and the problem you face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the image once, outside the animating function. Then for the animation you only need to change the image's position, i.e.

```
image.set_extent(...)
```

Complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.image as mgimg

fig, ax = plt.subplots( figsize=(4,4))
plt.axis([0, 200, 0, 300])

fname='https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuTST.png'
img = mgimg.imread(fname)[230:230+55,51:51+86]
imobj = ax.imshow(img,extent=[0, img.shape[1], 136, 136+img.shape[0]], zorder=1)

def animate(i):
    imobj.set_extent([0+i, img.shape[1]+i, 136, 136+img.shape[0]])
    return imobj,
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=100,  interval=40, repeat=False)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]